# Powershell command failing to run a file in a separate ps1 file

Tags: powershell

So I have 3 ps1 files - A.ps1, B.ps1 and C.ps1

B.ps1 contains logic to read and clean up each file and it imports functions from C.ps1 to implement most of its logic. So B.ps1 looks like:

```
. .\C.ps1
# Code ot clean up files using functions from C.ps1
```

From A.ps1, I execute B.ps1 for each file in the directory

```
$psa = [powershell]::Create()
$psa.RunspacePool = $runspacepool

$psa.AddScript("B.ps1 $($psitem) $($id)")
$handle = $psa.BeginInvoke()
```

For some reason, the functions do not execute. Since it runs in background, I am not even able to see the error.

But as soon as I copy all the functions from C.ps1 to B.ps1, everything starts working.

I am not sure what I am missing. Is there somethign wrong in the way I am importing C.ps1?

Comment: What's the purpose of dot-sourcing your scripts and using runspaces?

Comment: Regarding the errors, not quite true. I suggest you to log what's happening into a log file so you can investigate further.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Try making this work from any location without using runspaces and async. I would recommend not going down this path if you need parallel processing. Consider using jobs or even different processes using `Start-Process`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the relative path when you dot source.

**First :** Try to dot source from the full path.

**Second :** you can try to dot source from a path relative to the caller using `$PSScriptRoot` or formerly `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition`.